# Unable To Debug Into Native Code On Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, mcafee

Our VC++/C# SW product has recently migrated to a Windows 10 LTSB target. I am no longer able to see native modules in the 'Modules' tab in Visual Studio 2015 when I attach a debugger (either locally or remotely) to my managed process. I have checked the 'Enable native code debugging' in the C# project properties, and I have selected 'Managed (v4.6, v4.5, v4.0) and Native' for code type when I attach the remote debugger. I am able to debug the native code (running inside a managed process) just fine when running on the Windows 7 target.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Nate

Comment: Does it make any difference if you run Visual Studio as Admin?

Comment: @Nate Tater, If possible, please compare the VS settings under TOOLS->Options->Debugging, or the project property, view the result. Please also mark sure that your app was in debug mode, not release mode. Of course, if you get any debug log messages, please also share it.

Comment: @Nate Tater, What about this issue? Do you get any latest information in your side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem ended up being caused by McAfee Solidifier. Uninstalling this product or disabling it by calling 'sadmin disable' fixed the debugging issue.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could mark your solution as the answer. Have a nice day:)